# How can I use JavaScript to apply formatting to a <td> in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

So I am trying to apply JavaScript to an entire column in an Html table.

Below is my Script (please ignore the first daterange function but I wanted to show the full code):

All I am trying to do is add a breakline after each comma in the Message row of the table. Any idea where I am going wrong? Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({

     singleDatePicker: true,
     locale: {
         format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
     }
});

 function formatMessage() {
 var yourString = document.getElementById('msg').value;
 var formattedText = yourString.split(",").join("\n");
 $('msg').html(formattedText);
   }; 

});
</script>
```

Below is the relevant HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action">
  <thead>
    <tr class="headings">
        <th class="column-title">Message</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="statement in statements track by $index">
      <td class=" " id="msg" style="display:none;">{{statement.msg}}</td>
      <td class=" ">{{statement.msg}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ids are singular. Why are you not doing the transformation with angular?

Comment: Newlines are just whitespace in HTML; this is basic HTML.

Comment: This is my first time using angular, all of my online searches for solutions have been searching JavaScript. If there is a way to use Angular, I will research that

Comment: You are going to create multiple td with id=msg. Also $('msg') should be $('#msg') in jQuery if you want element by id.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that by having the ID='msg' for each row, then the formatting would apply to each row

Comment: You should not need to even have this code. A simple function call in your template can format the data....

Comment: @JohnBrofser - if you want to target or apply formatting to multiple elements, use a `class` instead. You can only have 1 instance of a unique `id` per page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all,

```
 var yourString = document.getElementById("msg").value;
```

is not the correct way to get the value of a "td" tag.
You shall do something like this.

```
var yourString_obj = document.getElementById("msg");
var yourString_text = yourString_obj.innerHTML;
```

or

```
var yourString = document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML;
```

For spliting the text and inserting the new line you shall use following functions.
    split()   join()
and use
`<br>`
for adding a new line to your text.

---

Following should solve your problem.

```
function formatMessage() {
var yourString = document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML;
var formattedText = yourString .split(",").join(",<br>");
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = formattedText ;
};
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`yourMessage.split(",").join("\n")` effectively replaces all occurrences of commas with a newline character.

If you want to *add* a newline character after each instance of a comma, try `yourMessage.split(",").join(",\n")`.

[MDN article on String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)